# Which CMS or e-Commerce system to use, i want site like this :

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I want to build website like this: http://biotechlab-bg.com . My target is to build this site like online shop (e-commerce), but without shopping basket(without add to cart and checkout).

I want only to show Item, Description of it and small table under description. It will show the price, but without add to cart option. Is there an option to disable shopping basket in magento ? It will be something like a showroom, not a direct e-shop. thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case i will not recommend magento. Because magento is used when you need a complete e-commerce solution. Here you need some cms platform which can display your data.

You can use any cms platforms like :-

1. Drupal (Best as per my point of view)
2. Word Press

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option to do this, but with some coding, you can disable ordering of products/adding to cart of products.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend Woocommerce which is an extension for Wordpress. It is very easy to use. You just need to code a couple of lines to disable the Cart Options.
http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/